# How to make space between a button in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

**I have a button in that I want to put a space between all buttons, so if I run an app in a tablet, the space between button will equal divide. I am using `LinearLayout`, and I know there is the layout_weight option, but I don't want to stretch the icon.**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutcornerbend"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/e"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutcornerbend"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/navi"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutcornerbend"
        android:id="@+id/stream"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/appstream"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: got solution for this .. add  <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                />

Comment: why not trying that before posting question

Comment: @VivekMishra Sometimes just writing the question helps you to think of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the great article by Cyril Mottier to add spacing when you use LinearLayout. Kindly follow this.

*[Grid Spacing on Android](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/11/17/grid-spacing-on-android/)* (2014)

Basically, you just have to use the parameter:

```xml
android:divider
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a margin:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutcornerbend"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/e"
        **android:layout_marginRight="10dp"**
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutcornerbend"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        **android:layout_marginRight="10dp"**
        android:src="@drawable/navi"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutcornerbend"
        android:id="@+id/stream"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/appstream"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="log in"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#E0B13B"/>

        <view
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="register"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#67A22C"/>

    </LinearLayout>>
```

Comment: Re revision 2: The XML may be nonsense, but at least it made a reference to the XML element  "view".

Comment: This is likely a bogus answer. The XML is syntactically incorrect (`</LinearLayout>>` and the "`view`" element is unlikely to exist (should it be "`View`"?))